# How to get barriers to work with MotionLayout

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

So I have been playing around with `MotionLayout` to get certain animations to work, but I had an issue with barriers when converting the `ConstraintLayout` to the `MotionLayout`.  I have a barrier that references two header views on the top of the parent layout and a `ViewGroup` that constrains the top of the `ViewGroup` to the bottom of the barrier; however, when I convert the `ConstraintLayout` to the new `MotionLayout`, the barrier does not work anymore.  My `ViewGroup` gets constrained to the top of the parent instead of the bottom of the barrier.  I assume this is because the library is still in alpha, but I'm hoping someone has some sort of workaround on that.

Edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.motion.MotionLayout 
    usual stuff here
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/scene">

    <CustomHeaderView
        android:id="@+id/first_header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:attachedRecyclerView="@+id/some_recycler_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <SecondCustomHeaderView
        android:id="@+id/second_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:attachedRecyclerView="@+id/some_recycler_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="first_header,second_header"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="241dp" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/some_swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/some_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


</android.support.constraint.motion.MotionLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, could you post the relevant code that you have so far?

Comment: Although not answering your question, the Android Dev Summit is today and there is a Session on ConstraintLayout and what's new in 2.0 which may be helpful to you.  https://developer.android.com/dev-summit/schedule/day1

Comment: @RX9 Yeah, give me a moment to post some shortened down code.

Comment: @RX9 The code is up!

Comment: @teh_raab Thanks for the link!  I'll be sure to check that out after work.

Comment: hi Sam, were you able to figure this out? i'm puzzled here as well

Comment: @ЄвгенГарастович Sorry, I was not able to figure this out.  I used a different animation library instead of using MotionLayout.  I did read an update about the latest MotionLayout library fixing some sort of barrier issue, but I have not played with MotionLayout for awhile.  Good luck with your code!